# Error while retrieving data from database table and get its value in label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I get an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

My class is

```
public void bil()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = (@"Server=DESKTOP-8JJO9NL\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HMS;Trusted_Connection=True");

    con.Open();

    string sqlquery = "select  DATEDIFF(day,arrivaldate,departure) AS TotalDays=@tdays ,(DATEDIFF(day,arrivaldate,departure) * 10) AS CalculatedAmount=@amount from Roomsdata where room#=@roomnum2";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);

    SqlDataReader sReader;

    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomnum2", Roomnum);

    sReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (sReader.Read())
    {
        Tdays = sReader["TotalDays"].ToString(); 
        Amount = sReader["CalculatedAmount"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();
```

More error details:

> Line 142:            command.Parameters.Clear();
>   Line 143:            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomnum2", Roomnum);
>   Line 144:            sReader = command.ExecuteReader();
>   Line 145:
>   Line 146:            while (sReader.Read())

Comment: error is in    Line 144:            sReader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Yes, line 144 is where the query string is actually parsed. The error is in the query string, near the `=` operator, just like the exception says.

Answer (score 1):

You did not initiate the @tdays and @amount parameters

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Yes, he is using three query arguments, but only setting one.

Comment: after deleting argument TotalDays value and CalculatedAmount is not get in label

Answer (score 0):

Why wrote "#" after where room? maybe that is error

Comment: its room# from database table

Comment: Maybe you need to quote it, SQL-style, as in `[room#]`.

Comment: What do you want to do each time you write "=@tdays?", "=@amount"

Comment: Execute the plain query in the SQL Server, for detect errors